# Can the GoogleBar's location on the map be changed?

Tags: google-maps

I'm using the [GoogleBar](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GGoogleBar) in the Google Maps API v2. Can the location of the GoogleBar be changed from the bottom left of the map? I'd like it at the top of my map.

Comment: Curious.. I'm trying to do the same.. and cant.. the following code should work, but doesnt: Tracker.map = new GMap2(Tracker.divMap,{googleBarOptions:{linkTarget:G_GOOGLEBAR_LINK_TARGET_TOP}});